# JQUERY or Java script popup loads table from div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey guys so i need  a function that opens a popup with a table being held by a div when an image or hyperlink is clicked heres my code

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="tabla"> </h1> </div>
<a href="#" id="openDialog">Click me</a> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       $( "#tabla" ).dialog({
          height: 140,
          modal: true
        });
       $( "#tabla" ).show();
    });
 });

</script>
```

theres the DIV ID holding the table so the function must call by the ID for the popup filled with the table THANKS GUYS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

HTML

```
<button id="trigger">
  open dialog
</button>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__body">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.modal__body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $('.modal').addClass('show');
});

$('.modal').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('show');
});
```

Just add your table to modal__body

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery UI` dialog to achieve what you are trying to do. If you give your div containing your table a `dialog` class:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <table></table
</div>
```

Then you need to hook into click event of your `a` tag or whatever you want to trigger the popup:

```
$( "#openDialog" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

Don't worry about closing since it has a close button on that dialog. More info [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).